# I need to loop through the email addresses in a table within a SQL Server database and all an Email

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, smtpclient, sqldatareader

I was wondering if someone could help me. I've got a simple `Suppliers` table that has email addresses for my suppliers.

I need to loop through the email addresses 'SuppEmail' in the `Suppliers` table in the SQL Server database `SpecCars` and send them all the email below.

I've been at it for a few days now, looking on-line and trying many different variations, but no matter what I do, it only sends one email
to the first entry `frontdesk@jacksauto.com.au` in the table and that's it.

If you could help, that would be fantastic. It's an ASP.NET C# solution.

This is the `Suppliers` table, it just has two records in there:

```
CREATE table Suppliers
(
    SuppId      INT IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
    SuppName    NVARCHAR(60)       NOT NULL, 
    SuppAddress NVARCHAR(150)      NOT NULL, 
    SuppSuburb  NVARCHAR(60)       NOT NULL, 
    SuppState   NVARCHAR(30)       NOT NULL, 
    SuppPost    NVARCHAR(10)       NOT NULL,
    SuppPhone   NVARCHAR(10)       NOT NULL,
    SuppEmail   NVARCHAR(100)      NOT NULL,
    SuppCode    NVARCHAR(10)       NOT NULL
)

Insert into Suppliers (SuppName, SuppAddress, SuppSuburb, SuppState, SuppPost, SuppPhone, SuppEmail, SuppCode) 
values ('Jacks Auto', '2 Jill Street', 'Belgrade', 'VIC', '3299', '9555 4457', 'frontdesk@jacksauto.com.au', 'JACBLA')

Insert into Suppliers (SuppName, SuppAddress, SuppSuburb, SuppState, SuppPost, SuppPhone, SuppEmail, SuppCode) 
values ('Ultimate Lights', '205 Browns Road', 'Tullamarine', 'VIC', '3011', '9877 2255', 'orders@ultimatlights.com.au', 'ULTTUL')
```

This is the code snippet :

```
  SqlDataReader sqlData;
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SpecCars;Integrated Security=True");

  connection.Open();
  sqlData = new SqlCommand("Select SuppEmail From Suppliers", connection).ExecuteReader();

  int count = sqlData.FieldCount;

  while (sqlData.Read())
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
      string emailnew = sqlData[i].ToString();

        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myemail.com");
        mailMessage.To.Add("myemail.com");
        mailMessage.To.Add(emailnew);
        //mailMessage.CC.Add(emailnew);
        mailMessage.Subject = "Assembly Line Stop";
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

        mailMessage.Body = "Please be advised that the assembly line at Specialised Cars has STOPPED. You will be notified once the line has started again. Any Services between the LINE STOP and the LINE START will be carried out after 19:00 (7pm).";
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.myprovider.com", 587);
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
        smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail.com", "password");
        smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
    }
}
connection.Close();
```

Comment: @chunk try to loop only for adding the emails then exectue the remaining part of the code like this ....

Comment: MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
             for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
              string emailnew = sqlData[i].ToString();
        
                 mailMessage.To.Add(emailnew);
        
            }
     
                mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myemail.com");
        mailMessage.Subject = "Assembly Line Stop";
        mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
     
          }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 //-----------------

//Hi All, just a quick update:


//Trying8.aspx - Finally Works, it sends LINE STOP Email to every SuppEmail recipient in Suppliers Table

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Trying8.aspx.cs" Inherits="SpecCars.Admin.Trying8" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
      <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
      <br />
      <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

//-----------------

//Trying8.aspx.cs - Finally Works, it sends LINE STOP Email to every SuppEmail recipient in Suppliers Table

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Text;

namespace SpecCars.Admin
{
  public partial class Trying8 : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      SqlDataReader sqlData;
      SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SpecCars;Integrated Security=True");
      connection.Open();

      sqlData = new SqlCommand("Select * From Suppliers", connection).ExecuteReader();
      using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.provider.com", 587))
      {
        while (sqlData.Read())
        {
          string emailnew = sqlData["SuppEmail"].ToString();
          Label1.Text = emailnew.ToString();

          using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
          {
            try
            {
              message.From = new MailAddress("myemail@outlook.com");
              // This doesn't Send (To:) myotheremail@yahoo.com.au
              MailAddress AddressTo = new MailAddress("myotheremail@yahoo.com.au");
              // This does Send (To:) to SuppEmail recipient in Suppliers Table
              message.To.Add(emailnew);
              //This does Send a (CC:) myotheremail@yahoo.com.au
              message.CC.Add("myotheremail@yahoo.com.au");
              message.Subject = "Assembly Line Stop";
              message.Priority = MailPriority.High;

              message.Body = "Please be advised that the assembly line at Specialised Cars has STOPPED. You will be notified once the line has started again. Any Services between the LINE STOP and the LINE START will be carried out after 19:00 (7pm).";
              message.IsBodyHtml = true;

              smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
              smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail@outlook.com", "password");
              smtpClient.Send(message);
              // smtpClient.Dispose();
              // message.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
              //log exceptions here, you can write it to a txt file, or to a label in your form for testing purpose
              //we are trying to see if you get an exception..
              Label1.Text = ex.Message;
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
}

//-----------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var mailMessage = CreateMessage();
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=SpecCars;Integrated Security=True"))
{
    connection.Open();
    using(var sqlData = new SqlCommand("Select SuppEmail From Suppliers", connection).ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (sqlData.Read())
        {
            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(emailnew);
        }
    }
}
SendMessage(mailMessage)


private MailMessage CreateMessage()
{
    var mailMessage = new MailMessage();
    mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myemail.com");
    mailMessage.To.Add("myemail.com");

    mailMessage.Subject = "Assembly Line Stop";
    mailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;

    mailMessage.Body = "Please be advised that the assembly line at Specialised Cars has STOPPED. You will be notified once the line has started again. Any Services between the LINE STOP and the LINE START will be carried out after 19:00 (7pm).";
    mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
    return mailMessage;
}

private void SendMessage(MailMessage mailMessage)
{
    var smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp-mail.myprovider.com", 587);
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("myemail.com", "password");
    smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

Note: this code can be and should be better. Consider refactoring to get the connectionstring and mail settings from web.config instead of having them hard-coded in your application.

Comment: Hi Zohar,

Thanks for that, I tried pasting the code into a Button but I have red squiggly lines under the 'BBC and emailnew' in the 'mailMessage.BCC.Add(emailnew);' line
Error 6 'System.Net.Mail.MailMessage' does not contain a definition for 'BCC' and no extension method 'BCC' accepting a first argument of type could be found

and a red squiggly line after the 'SendMessage(mailMessage)' line
Error 6 ; expected, when I add it, it the throw Error 3 } expected 

and a red squiggly line after the last '}'
Error 4 Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected

Is it possible to test.

Comment: @Chuck sorry, my mistak. should be `Bcc` and not `BCC`. A quick search would have given you [this.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bcc(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hey Zohar, I've tried this and various other things and still get the same errors. Can you please try the code and let me know if you get the same errors.

Comment: I've got an exception on `mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("myemail.com");` that said that `"myemail.com"` is not a valid format for an email address. Once I've changed all the `"myemail.com"` to `"my@email.com"` I didn't get any exceptions.

Comment: Hi Zohar,

I've amended the code and it still just sending one email, without an exception. I've just used myemail.com and smtp-mail.myprovider.com" in this code. In my code, I've used my proper personal email and smtp syntax, and in the Suppliers table, I have used two of my personal email addresses as well. I just don't get why its not looping through the table and sending the same email to both email addresses.

Comment: Just for the test, add these addresses as `CC` instead of the `Bcc`, and add a `Reapone.Write` of them in the loop. You should see both on the screen as well as in the email itself. I have a feeling it's not a code problem.